# spring boot - application yml for each developer

Tags: spring-boot

In my work the fields in application.yml are dynamics and each developer have another (dynamic) configuration. So, we have the general yml section, that relevant for all of us (and have updates from time to time) and the “private profile”

Like this:

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  configuration:
    ...
    ...

spring:
  profiles: development1
configuration: ...

spring:
  profiles: development2
configuration: ...
```

We have “small” problems with this (mistakes, conflicts, etc.) and we’re look for solution.
I think about separate yml file for each developer, such as:

```
spring:
  profiles: development1
configuration:
  yml-file: app_dev1.yml

spring:
  profiles: development2
configuration:
  yml-file: app_dev2.yml
```

but didn’t find how to do this…

Will be glad to know if it can be done? (or you have another way to separate the yml between us).

We do not want to set an application yaml with annotation (git issues again..), something like `Environment Variables`...

Comment: There is no way to load a file holding a properties configuration inside an application.property. For this the PropertySource Annotation exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring boot by default loads `application.yaml` but in addition if you run with `--spring.profiles.active=dev1` it will load file `application-dev1.yaml`

So you could create yaml file per developer + have some "common" configuration in `application.yaml`

With such an approach you won't need lines like:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev1
```

... in any of the yaml files